# clion: exclude files from project view

Tags: clion

My Project View in CLion lists not only C++ files and headers but also built libraries (.la) and object files (.o). I don't want to see them. What can I do to make them not appear in the list?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the menu go to `Files/Settings`: in the dialog box chose the item `File types`. The last field in the dialog is `Ignored files and folders`. It contains semicolon-separated patterns that will be applied and, if the file matches one of these, ignored. Wildcards like `*` are allowed.

So just add `;*.la;*.o` at the end.

Comment: It seems it can't help with nested expressions: e.g. `bin/*.so` is forbidden because of `/` character.

Answer (score 3):

You can also define a so-called "Scope" by clicking on the gear icon at the right of the project view's header bar -> "Edit scopes". This will present you with a nice ui to define your filter. Afterwards, click on the triangle next to "Project" in the project view header bar and select your newly created scope.

Comment: Cleary what I needed. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version control(git) you can also add the file extensions to the `.gitignore` file and Clion should hide those files as well. If you're not using version control then adding the file extensions to the Clion `Ignored files and folders` list.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't hide ".gitignore" like this, even if it's in .gitignore.